# onActivityResult data transfer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm following this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html for having some data transfered to parent activity by calling an activity with startActivityForResult.

Basicly i’m trying to finish parent activity, on some buttons clicked but not onBackPressed. I do not know if there is a easier way or not. Like this:

```
MainPage to NewTarget
            NewTarget to Target

// onBackPressed
            Target to NewTarget

// onButtonClick on TargetActivity
            Target to MainPage
```

The problem is onActivityResult calls when i click the button on NewTarget activity, not on Target activity finish?? Shouldn’t it be opposite?

On “NewTarget” class, i’ve got a button which needs to call an activity onClick. And i also need some feedBack on activity, named “Target”, like it’s been finished by back button or some other way (which i need to finish that activity on some point click, and i called “finish()”)

From NewTarget activity:

```
public void savingClick(View v) {
    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, Target.class);
    targetIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(targetIntent, 5);
}
```

On Target activity:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
if(ClickCheck) {
    Log.d("Target","ClickCheck");
    // Prepare data intent 
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("returnKey", "click");
    // Activity finished ok, return the data
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
}
super.finish();
```

}

And finally on NewTarget activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("NewTarget","requestCode: " + requestCode);
    Log.d("NewTarget","resultCode: " + resultCode);
    if(requestCode == 5 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("NewTarget","data: " + data.hasExtra("returnKey"));
        if(data.hasExtra("returnKey"))
            this.finish();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And i check the values:

```
// these lines have appeared when i clicked on button to startActivityForResult
requestCode: 5
resultCode: 5
// ClickCheck line has appeared on Target activity finished.
// data: data.hasExtra("returnKey")); line has never been appeared.
```

So what’s the deal? What am i overlooking? Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: what you want to achieve , can you please tell in simple

Comment: I've editted my question with a schematic explation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this:

```
MainPage to NewTarget
        NewTarget to Target

// onBackPressed
        Target to NewTarget

// onButtonClick on TargetActivity
        Target to MainPage
```

You don't need to use `startActivityForResult()` unless you need to have some data returned from `Target` to `NewTarget`. The normal behaviour will be that pressing "back" in `Target` will just call `finish()` on Target and return to `NewTarget` (that seems to be what you want). To get the last behaviour you should just use the following code in `Target.onButtonClick()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will finish both `NewTarget` and `Target` and then it will finish the current `MainPage` activity and create a new instance of the `MainPage` activity (if the launchMode of `MainPage` is "standard").

Try this.

Comment: Also, you should definitely remove the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` from the Intent you use to start `Target`

Comment: I just didn't want to start mainPage activity all over again, because it takes too long. But I've managed what i want to do by just changing this line: targetIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); into this: targetIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); Thanks for the answer =)

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can prevent it from starting another instance using combinations of launchMode and intent flags. Glad you were able to fix it!